Refresh MTLS Webclient instance's SSLContext during runtime for automatic certificate rotation
I am using sprint 6 with webClient implementation for making calls to downstreams. I need to connect to one of the downstream over MTLS. For that, I am creating a secured HttpClient by setting SSLProvider information.
The SSLProvider info is being read from database.
The mtls webClient is being created at the startup of the application, so first the ssl information is being read from the database and then being passed to HttpClient to further create the mtls webclient.
Problem statement: I want to implement the automatic certificate rotation mechanism for mtls webclient but unable to find any solution. I am lookinf for a solution to refresh the webclient connection pool with new certificates at runtime.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
